# Using the OData endpoint to update or insert assignment in Project Server 2013 On Premise

Tags: development, rest, csom, project-server, odata

**Objective**

Connect to Project Server 2013 in order to update an existing assignment of a resource to a task or create a new assignment for the resource in case it (the resource) is not assigned to the particular task.

---

**Context info**

The tasks are identified by project and by a custom field called *EnterpriseAbs* (more tasks can have the same value). The assignments are identified by task and *resourceId*. The update operation is meant only for the update of the assignment units.

Assignments can be created/updated for normal projects and also for master projects. That excludes the use of **CSOM** being that [master projects cannot be read/updated](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2e4e47e6-46cc-4f68-aa48-c7e2670b7e01/how-to-update-a-master-project-in-project-online-via-csom-or-rest?forum=project2010custprog). The idea was to use the OData Endpoint in order to do the operations. Considering the situation I added a service reference to the endpoint. It's all nice and good with querying the data using the context, but as soon as I want to make some changes I can't because:

- I can't find a way to check out the project,
- It throws an `SPException` with the message

> "The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again."

as soon as I try to save the changes.

The method that does the operation is the following:

```
private IHttpActionResult UpsertViaOData(Guid projectId, 
                                         string abs, 
                                         AssignmentInformation assignment, 
                                         ProjectODataContainer.ReportingData container, 
                                         ProjectContext context)
{
    var tasks = container.Tasks.Where(t => t.ProjectId == projectId
                                        && t.EnterpriseABS == abs)
                               .ToList();
    if (tasks.Count == 0)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
    var project = container.Projects.Where(p => p.ProjectId == projectId)
                                    .ToList()
                                    .FirstOrDefault();
    if (project == default(ProjectODataContainer.Project))
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    var resourceId = assignment.Resource.Id;
    var assignments = container.Assignments.Where(a => a.ProjectId == projectId
                                                    && a.ResourceId == resourceId)
                                           .ToDictionary(a => a.TaskId, a => a);
    foreach (var task in tasks)
    {
        ProjectODataContainer.Assignment taskAssignment;
        if (assignments.TryGetValue(task.TaskId, out taskAssignment))
        {
            // assignment already exists
            if (taskAssignment.AssignmentPeakUnits != assignment.Units)
            {
                taskAssignment.AssignmentPeakUnits = assignment.Units;
                container.UpdateObject(taskAssignment);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // assignment does not exist
            taskAssignment = new ProjectODataContainer.Assignment
            {
                TaskId = task.TaskId,
                AssignmentId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                ProjectId = projectId,
                AssignmentPeakUnits = assignment.Units
            };
            container.AddToAssignments(taskAssignment);
        }
    }

    // This is the instruction that throws the aforementioned Exception
    container.SaveChanges(System.Data.Services.Client.SaveChangesOptions.PatchOnUpdate);

    return Ok();
}
```

with `ProjectODataContainer.ReportingData` being the context and `AssignmentInformation` being defined as follows:

```
public class AssignmentInformation
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ResourceInformation Resource { get; set; }
    public Guid TaskId { get; set; }
    public decimal? Units { get; set; }

    public AssignmentInformation() { }
}
```

Seems like it is an authorization problem, but the credentials with which the context runs have the right privileges (the same credentials used with CSOM do the job, but - as I wrote before - CSOM cannot be used with master projects).

Anybody has an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

"The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again."

That is a formdigest issue. You need to add a "X-RequestDigest" header.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints#writing-data-by-using-the-rest-interface